# Batch code to print each path entry in a new row?

Tags: batch-file

Can any share a batch script that prints each batch entry in a new row?

eg - if `Path = C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts`

Then it shall get printed as

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a VBscript that does this:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
pathList = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PATH%")

dirs = Split(pathList, ";", -1, 1)

For i = 0 to UBound(dirs)
   WScript.Echo dirs(i)
Next
```

Save it as e.g. `list_path.vbs` and you can use it just like any other batch file.

If you can't run it by entering `list_path` you need to adjust the value of `PATH_EXT` in order to include `.vbs` (but I think that is the default in modern Windows versions - I can't remember having to adjust that)